# How to debug this WCF webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF Ajax enabled web service that I call via jquery. It returns fine when I test it by just returning a string. As soon as I add some more functionality, the javascript error callback runs with no useful data. Just says 'error', readystate=0, status=0.

I can step through the service code and it returns an array of objects succesfully. The client doesn't however.

Here's the code.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WebAPI
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Person[] GetPeople(Guid groupId)
    {
        using (SchedulerContext context = new SchedulerContext())
        {
            return context.People.Where(p=>p.Group_ID==groupId).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "json",
                    data: { groupId: 'ae09a080-5d7c-4e92-9a87-591574b7c4b8' },
                    url: "WebAPI.svc/GetPeople",
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                }

        );
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
Inspecting it with fiddler, the http result is 504 and in the 'raw' response tab has the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 13:52:46.107

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

**UPDATE - 2012/05/04:** *(btw, happy star wars day everyone!)*
I figured out that the problem was in the JSON serialising. It gives a Circular Reference Exception on my entity model. Still working on a solution.

Comment: i guess your content type should be "application/json" rather than just "json". Can you try that by changing it. Also do inspect your request using Fiddler, If you still get an error try to create a simple data contract and populate the People objects into it and return that as the json serializer at times cannot serialize entity framework objects

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I have changed the dataType as you specified, but no success. Is Fiddler any different from Firebug's Net panel? I can see the GET request for http://localhost:15006/WebAPI.svc/GetPeople?groupId=739526F1-7C58-4E3B-97D8-4870948BFE32. It has a ststus of Aborted and no response. Could you elaborate on creating a data contract? What would it involve?

Comment: Please see the update above regarding fiddler result.

Comment: See my answer below and i was suggesting on inspecting the request first in Fiddler that was generated from your jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify your service method definition to below:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WebAPI
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="GetPeople/{groupId}",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Person[] GetPeople(Guid groupId)
    {
        using (SchedulerContext context = new SchedulerContext())
        {
            return context.People.Where(p=>p.Group_ID==groupId).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Now perform a GET request from Fiddler with the request as below:

```
GET http://localhost:15006/WebAPI.svc/GetPeople/739526F1-7C58-4E3B-97D8-4870948BFE32 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: localhost
```

Now try to perform the same from your jquery call and see how the request looks.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is not the request, but the response. I can debug it on the server and the guid property is sent in succesfully. I even get the array of entities, but the problem comes when I try to serialise the entities. Please see the update above.

Comment: Rather than sending the r entity framework object directly create a simple poco ANC return that and the Jason serializer should work??

Comment: Thanks. Marked this as the answer, because it is a good solution, although I ended up projecting the linq query into an anonymous type. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to debug this issue:

- [Enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) at the server. If it returned an error response, it should contain some information in the tracing explaining what went wrong
- Use some network capture tool such as Fiddler, or the developer tools in most browsers (press F12 to access them, then go to the network tab). By capturing the actual response, you can see if the response has some additional information to help you nail the problem.
- Use extra parameters in your error function on the `$.ajax` call. The [error callback takes 3 parameters](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown), you can query the jqXHR for its `status` or `responseText` properties, which should give you more information on the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I use firebug to view all the http activity in this. It doesn't give any more details than what I posted. Adding in the extra parameters also just returns a string "error" for textStatus and an empty string for errorThrown. It returns succesfully if my server method returns an empty result set. Could it be something to do with the objects I return? Do they need to be serializable for json specifically (I mean in a different way than applying the Serializable Attribute)?

Comment: Try enabling tracing on the server, that should give you more information about the issue.